# Form data payload doesn't work with delete request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, ecmascript-6

the API needs a Form data payload to delete an item when I pass it to the service it doesn't appear in the network and it gives me 500 internal server error

```
  unsavePost(data){
    debugger
    return this.http.delete('saved_links',data);
  }
```

put it works with this function with POST requests

```
  savePost(data){
    debugger
    return this.http.post(`saved_links`, data);
  }
```

this is the functino call in the ts:

```
  unsavePost(post:News){
    debugger
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('saved_linkable_id', post.id);
    formData.append('type', 'news');
    this.newsHealthtipsService.unsavePost(formData).subscribe(res=>{

    })
  }
```

there is an old version of the website built with emberjs and this function works well in it

[image: this is a screenshot from the working website]

the form data payload appears in the network at the bootom

also this is a screenshot from my network, the form data payload doesn't appear in the network 
[image]

Comment: how this methods are called?

Comment: unsavePost(post:News){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('saved_linkable_id', post.id);
    formData.append('type', 'news');
    this.newsHealthtipsService.unsavePost(formData).subscribe(res=>{

    })
  }

Comment: How you're sure that your API accepts the `delete` request?

Comment: there is an old version of the system built with emberjs and this function works well in it but when i tried to reimplement it i faced this problem

Comment: any log of the HTTP request (return code, content, stacktrace...) ? Please update the question with new data instead of pasting it in comments.

Comment: i updated the question please check it again

Comment: the request return a 500 error code, so this is a backend problem. You're server does not allow your front-end to call the delete API...

Comment: so why does it work on the current system ?

Comment: can't know with so few informations. Since it is a 500 error, you should see logs on the backend server